# Swift how to manage multiple requests and reponse in search api

Tags: ios, swift

i am working on a project in which there is a search bar and a table view. the flow is like following,
when a character is typed a request is created and response is shown in the tableview.
So i want to implement like if i type
"coronory" -> shows the results with coronory
then i erase the "ry" -> 
"corono" -> if the previous request is not completed, cancel it -> make request for "corono" and show the data in table view!
And the multiple response should also be managed and only the latest search result should be shown in the tableview.(I am using almofire for api calling)

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: If you need to able to cancel your previous request before actually making it in case the user types "too fast", you should look into Combine or RxSwift. That way you can also save a lot of networking and tableview reloading

Comment: @dahiya_boy- the issue is when i enter a string in search bar than is sometimes shows the result of previous request. example a keyword cor contains 100 results and corz contains 0 results than sometimes i got result of corz= 100

Comment: are you using searchview controller?

Comment: I imagine you are needing to leave an asynchronous function if it hasn't completed/updated the table view's data before the text in the search bar updates? AKA autocompletion? This is a common question people have with `UISearchBar`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using a search view controller and do type in the search view controller and on type of each character you make a call on the server to get results related to the entered word. There is a delegate for `UISearchViewController`. You can use `cancelPreviousPerformRequests`, you can use your own `searchViewModel` to get data from server. this will prevent fast searching.

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
// This prevent multiple server call, make delay in each call
    NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: 
#selector(self.reload(_:)), object: searchController.searchBar)
    perform(#selector(self.reload(_:)), with: searchController.searchBar, afterDelay: 0.75)
}

@objc func reload(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    guard let query = searchBar.text, query.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) != "" else {
        print("nothing to search")
        return
    }

    print(query)
    self.searchViewModel.getData(searchWord: query) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } 
    }
}
```